# Translate Unicode to ascii (if possible)

Tags: python, unicode

There are some unicode characters which could simplified to ascii without loosing much.

Example:

```
>>> unicodedata.name(u'-')
'HYPHEN-MINUS'

>>> unicodedata.name(u'−')
'MINUS SIGN'
```

In above case I prefer "HYPHEN-MINUS", since "MINUS SIGN" is not ascii.

I could write my own translator easily, but I don't like re-inventing the wheel.

Is there no simpler way to translate special unicode characters to simple ascii characters?

I know this is guessing and only works for some unicode characters, but that's ok in this context.

Comment: Simplest way: use a mapping like you did, but don't re-invent the wheel. Use [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) instead (and yes, it maps MINUS SIGN to HYPHEN-MINUS).

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the perfect answer. 
Unicode consortium has draft [TR36](http://unicode.org/reports/tr36/) to deal with character similarities in unicode(not just ASCII).

You can search for python modules that the developer make the best effort to map them. A proof of concept homoglyph attack for similar looking to ascii character and symbol unicode character [can be found here](http://www.irongeek.com/homoglyph-attack-generator.php). (Due to font issues, some character or symbol might shown as square boxes by your browser)

You can make use of these [python confusable homoglyphs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/confusable_homoglyphs) package. The documentation is shown [here](http://confusable-homoglyphs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidocumentation.html).

```
from confusable_homoglyphs import confusables
confusables.is_confusable.is_confusable("-")
```

results

> [{'homoglyphs': [{'c': '‐', 'n': 'HYPHEN'}, {'c': '‑', 'n':
>   'NON-BREAKING HYPHEN'}, {'c': '‒', 'n': 'FIGURE DASH'}, {'c': '–',
>   'n': 'EN DASH'}, {'c': '﹘', 'n': 'SMALL EM DASH'}, {'c':
>   '\u200e۔\u200e', 'n': 'ARABIC FULL STOP'}, {'c': '⁃', 'n': 'HYPHEN
>   BULLET'}, {'c': '˗', 'n': 'MODIFIER LETTER MINUS SIGN'}, {'c': '−',
>   'n': 'MINUS SIGN'}, {'c': '➖', 'n': 'HEAVY MINUS SIGN'}, {'c': 'Ⲻ',
>   'n': 'COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER DIALECT-P NI'}], 'alias': 'COMMON',
>   'character': '-'}]

Now you need to decide which is your preferable remap. Checkout the source code if you want to take some concept out of the libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I was not aware of the term "Homoglyph" before. This and the link to the python package helped a lot. BTW, I added this to my list "join softwarerecs and stackoverflow": https://github.com/guettli/join-stackoverflow-and-softwarerecs/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Why is this no "perfect" answer according to your point of view?

Comment: @guettli  Because you ask for a ready made unicode to ascii mapper.   The Homoglphy-confusables author will make the best effort to map most character, which need continuous feedback and contribution to make it better.

Comment: for the answer is very good. .. I don't like the word "perfect". It sound like mature, sounds like "no progress" :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is useful information regarding inconsistnecies in unicode character naming here:
[Python library to translate multi-byte characters into 7-bit ASCII in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249708/python-library-to-translate-multi-byte-characters-into-7-bit-ascii-in-python/38546340#38546340)
and here:
[Translating multi-byte characters into 7-bit ASCII in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176258/translating-multi-byte-characters-into-7-bit-ascii-in-python)

But to answer your questionm it looks like there is no standard library for translating multi-byte unicode into ascii.  See the second link if you do not yet have your own solution.