# How to convert messed up string to plain text

Tags: python, unicode

I am using python3 to receive and process text messages from a telegram channel. I sometimes get messages containing a string like this:

```
Ехchanges: Віnance Futures
```

Looking pretty normal. But when I want to check

```
if 'Exchanges' in the_string:
```

I get

```
False
```

Trying to track this down:

```
the_string.encode()
```

yields

```
b'\xd0\x95\xd1\x85changes: \xd0\x92\xd1\x96nance Futures'
```

How can I convert this to a usual string?

```
'Exchanges: Binance Futures'
```

Comment: In your example, it looks like the first character is `U+0415 Cyrillic Capital Letter Ie`. It looks identical to the ASCII character `E`, but the visual similarity is a red herring, and you shouldn't expect Python to treat the characters as equal to each other just because they look they same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translate Unicode to ascii (if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367355/translate-unicode-to-ascii-if-possible) or [Where is Python's “best ASCII for this Unicode” database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/816285/4518341)

Comment: @water_ghosts this makes sense. I will use the not - russian string then for the if condition. You can add this as an answer, I will mark it as solved

Comment: BTW, instead of using encoding for that analysis, you could use `ascii()`, which shows characters instead of bytes: `print(ascii(the_string))` -> `'\u0415\u0445changes: \u0412\u0456nance Futures'`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use encode() and decode() methods of the str class mixed together:

```
>>> my_string = 'Ехchanges: Віnance Futures'
>>> 'Ехchanges' in my_string
True
>>> my_string.encode()
b'\xd0\x95\xd1\x85changes: \xd0\x92\xd1\x96nance Futures'
>>> 'Ехchanges' in my_string.encode().decode()
True
>>>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Ехchanges: Віnance Futures this is the original string. I just wrote it as normal in the above example. The bytes representation is the correct one though. If I do encode and then decode, I get a correct looking string but still a False on the if condition.

Comment: `'Ехchanges' in my_string` -> `True`??? You missed the whole point of the question.

Answer (score -1):

It's `utf-8` encoded string. You need to use string decoder `decode('utf-8')` here.

Solution:

```
encoded_string = b'\xd0\x95\xd1\x85changes: \xd0\x92\xd1\x96nance Futures'
decoded_string = encoded_string.decode("utf-8")
print(decoded_string)
```

Comment: Doesn't do what it should... The string looks correct, yes. But the if condition is still False.

Comment: `the_string` is a string. OP only tried encoding it to see what the underlying characters are.

Comment: Also, technically, you're talking about `bytes` objects, not `str`.